# Frame Processor threw an error: Can't find variable: __scanFaces // vision-camera-face-detector

Tags: react-native, face-detection, react-native-reanimated, react-native-vision-camera

I'm building a React Native app that uses the **react-native-vision-camera** package for face detection. I've also installed **vision-camera-face-detector** package to enable face detection. However, when I try to run the app and use the **scanFaces** function from vision-camera-face-detector, I get the error **"Can't find variable: __scanFaces"** in my Frame Processor.

```
import { scanFaces } from "vision-camera-face-detector";

const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
  const scannedFaces = scanFaces(frame);
  if (scannedFaces.length) {
    runOnJS(setFaces)(scannedFaces);
  }
}, []);
```

My babel.config file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset", "module:react-native-dotenv"],
  env: {
    production: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding"],
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanFaces'],
      },
    ], // NOTE: this must be last in the plugins
  ],
}
```

I'm currently using these versions:

```
`"react": "17.0.2",
 "react-native": "^0.64.2", // migrated from 0.63.3 to 0.64.2 to install vision camera
 "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-beta.2", 
 "react-native-vision-camera": "2.13.0", 
 "vision-camera-face-detector": "^0.1.7", //  Tried  "0.1.8" and "0.1.7" `
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version from

> "react-native-vision-camera": "2.13.0"

to

> "react-native-vision-camera": "2.15.4",

clean and rebuild the project.
Now it works fine for me.